# showing different div tag for individual img links when clicked

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have 4 image links that when clicked need to show a specific DIV. Then when another of the remaining 3 images is clicked, its DIV shows whilst hiding the last DIV. I have tried several different ways and can't seem to get it going the way I need. The four DIVs occupy the same space on the page. Can anyone help?

Here is how I have set up the HTML so far:

```
<div id="content">

  <div id="info">
  <a href="#"><img src="../Images/yellowbutton.png" class="infolink" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="../Images/redbutton.png" class="infolink"/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="../Images/greenbutton.png" class="infolink" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="../Images/bluebutton.png" class="infolink"/></a>

         <div id="level0">This is the home page for the levels</div>
         <div id="level1">this is the information on level 1</div>          
         <div id="level2">this is the information on level 2</div>
         <div id="level3">this is the information on level 3</div>
         <div id="level4">this is the information on level 4</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility of the divs using `css` and `javascript`

The following code performs the desired behaviour, (if I understood it correctly :-)):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function selectItem(item) {
    var availableItems = document.getElementsByClassName("itemToShow");   

    for (var i=0;i<availableItems.length;i++) {
        if (availableItems[i].id == item) {
            availableItems[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            availableItems[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">

  <div id="info">
  <a href="#" onclick="selectItem('level1')"><img src="../Images/yellowbutton.png" class="infolink" /></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="selectItem('level2')"><img src="../Images/redbutton.png" class="infolink"/></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="selectItem('level3')"><img src="../Images/greenbutton.png" class="infolink" /></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="selectItem('level4')"><img src="../Images/bluebutton.png" class="infolink"/></a>

         <div id="level0">This is the home page for the levels</div>
         <div id="level1" class="itemToShow">this is the information on level 1</div>          
         <div id="level2" style="display:none;" class="itemToShow">this is the information on level 2</div>
         <div id="level3" style="display:none;" class="itemToShow">this is the information on level 3</div>
         <div id="level4" style="display:none;" class="itemToShow">this is the information on level 4</div>

  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

The basic idea is call a javascript function when the anchor is clicked, passing the id of the DIV that must be shown.

Then, on the javascript funcion, select the DIVs by css class (`itemToShow`). For each DIV selected, set `style="display:block"` if its id is equal to the informed one or `style="display:none"` otherwise.